# Keyword 'using' only if condition holds

Tags: c#, dry

I am coding with the class **`Transaction`** for .NET and in this specific method I only wish to reinstantiate the **`Transaction`** instance if it is **not** instantiated already. Below is an example done together with some Entity Framework methods.

```
if (Transaction.Current != null)
{
    using (var transaction = CreateTransaction())
    {
        _dbSet.Attach(item);
        _dbSet.Remove(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Complete();
    }
}
else
{
    _dbSet.Attach(item);
    _dbSet.Remove(item);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I was wondering if there is a smarter way to only use the `using`-line if the condition above holds. I do not like repeating the same code twice.

Comment: Did you mean `if (Transaction.Current == null)` (instead of `!=`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking, you could write something like this (because if `transaction` is `null`, no auto-dispose will happen as the result of `using`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx):

```
using (var transaction = Transaction.Current == null ? CreateTransaction() : null)
{
    _dbSet.Attach(item);
    _dbSet.Remove(item);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    if(transaction != null)
        transaction.Complete();
}
```

**(I'm not sure about the check. In the original code `Transaction.Current != null`, however `Transaction.Current == null` looks more logical.)**

But I would consider just grouping

```
_dbSet.Attach(item);
_dbSet.Remove(item);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

into a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a new transaction scope that's within the existing one if one already exists?

But the best thing to do would likely just return a dummy `IDisposable` if a new transaction doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check if a transaction already exists. if one doesn't create one for
// the purpose of the following changes
Transaction transaction = Transaction.Current == null
  ? CreateTransaction()
  : null;

// changes
_dbSet.Attach(item);
_dbSet.Remove(item);
_context.SaveChanges();

// if we did end up creating one, let's clean up after it.
if (transaction != null)
{
    transaction.Complete();
    transaction.Dispose();
}
```

Something like that perhaps? (*Though this may be a better question for CodeReview*)